# rails string substitution or similar solution in controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building a site with users in all 50 states.  We need to display information for each user that is specific to their situation, e.g., the number of events they completed in that state.  Each state's view (a partial) displays state-specific information and, therefore, relies upon state-specific calculations in a state-specific model.  We'd like to do something similar to this:

@#{user.state} = #{user.state.capitalize}.new(current_user)

in the users_controller instead of

```
@illinois = Illinois.new(current_user) if (@user.state == 'illinois')
.... [and the remaining 49 states]
@wisconsin = Wisconsin.new(current_user) if (@user.state == 'wisconsin')
```

to trigger the Illinois.rb model and, in turn, drive the view defined in the users_controller by

```
def user_state_view
  @user = current_user
  @events = Event.all
  @illinois = Illinois.new(current_user) if (@user.state == 'illinois')
end
```

I'm struggling to find a better way to do this / refactor it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid dynamically defining instance variables if you can help it. It can be done with `instance_variable_set` but it's unnecessary. There's no reason you need to define the variable as `@illinois` instead of just `@user_state` or something like that. Here is one way to do it.

First make a static list of states:

```
def states
  %{wisconsin arkansas new_york etc}
end
```

then make a dictionary which maps those states to their classes:

```
def state_classes
  states.reduce({}) do |memo, state|
    memo[state] = state.camelize.constantize
    memo
  end
end
# = { 'illinois' => Illinois, 'wisconsin' => Wisconsin, 'new_york' => NewYork, etc }
```

It's important that you hard-code a list of state identifiers somewhere, because it's not a good practice to pass arbitrary values to `contantize`.

Then instantiating the correct class is a breeze:

```
@user_state = state_classes[@user.state].new(current_user)
```

there are definitely other ways to do this (for example, it could be added on the model layer instead)

Comment: Good idea, but you forgot about `NorthCarolina`, `NewMexico` and few others. Simple `state.capitalize` might not work for compound names if they are CamelCased. I suppose it would be better to hardcode those instead.

Comment: @BartoszPietraszko yes you're right, good catch. I changed it to `camelize` which will handle `north_carolina` too

Comment: Thank you for responding.  When I add the code to the users_controller, I get this error `undefined method each_with_object for "illinois" "wisconsin" "arkansas":String`  (I changed single quotes around the state names to " so they'd print nice.)  So, I changed the syntax of the `def state_classes` line `states.each ...` to `%w(states).each ...` per the `each_with_object` documentation's example [https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object] and now get the error `uninitialized constant States` for the line beginning `memo[state]`

Comment: I tried adding `belongs_to :state` in model user.rb and `has_many :users` in model Illinois.rb however that did not help.

Comment: if you don't have `each_with_object` available for whatever reasonn (older version of ruby, maybe), you can use `reduce` instead, see the question edit. Also, from the sounds of it, you are introducing more bugs as you try to debug ...  for example nowhere in my code did I mention `States` with a capital `S` ... the capitalization makes it a constant, it's different than saying `states` which calls the method. Also `%w(states)` is wrong, that's the same thing as saying `["states"].each` and you don't want to process the literal strinng `"states"`

Comment: Conntinuing my previous comment, the reason you are saying `undefined method States` is because you are passing "states" as the name of a state ...

Comment: Here's what worked for me:
1.  In the `users_controller.rb`, I created `def state_class` with `@user = current_user` and `state_class = @user.state.camelize.constantize` This works because `state` is a user attribute saved to the db. 
2. In the `def user_cpe_dashboard` method I added `@user_state = state_class.new(current_user)` replacing `@illinois = Illinois.new(current_user) if (@user.state == 'illinois')` and
3. In the view (a state-specific partial), I changed `@illinois.illinois_hours` to `user_state.illinois_hours`

Comment: @maxpleaner  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  If my changes make sense to you, and you wish to, please edit your answer.  I'll accept it after you give me the go ahead.

Comment: @user3763682 you are free to edit my answer, however I'm still not really sure why you think my code doesn't work (other than the reduce vs each_with_object thing). Note that there _is_ a difference between your approach and mine, and that's the fact that I whitelist user states before calling constantize. Like I mentioned, it's good practice not to pass user input to `constantize` without validating it first.

Comment: @maxpleaner I'm accepting your answer; hopefully, the thread will help someone else.  I validate a user's state before it's saved to the db.  Thanks again!